# Javascript voice control of html DOM

Tags: html, jquery, speech-recognition

I work on sorting images on a website. I am given option to click either one of three buttons depending on the number of people in an image. The buttons have the below html structure and IDs.

```
<div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <button id="radio-0-choice-btn" class="submit-btn second-choice-btn">None</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <button id="radio-1-choice-btn" class="submit-btn second-choice-btn">One</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <button id="radio-2-choice-btn" class="submit-btn second-choice-btn">Two</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <button id="radio-3-choice-btn" class="submit-btn second-choice-btn">Three +</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

So if I decide the answer is button "Two", I want to be able to click ID "radio-2-choice-btn" using voice command.

Pardon me if I posted in the wrong group

Comment: Where is your `.on('click', function(e){});` event handler code?

Comment: How to I link the (.on('click', function(e){});) function to a voice command, which one works offline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button on website using java-script and speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607560/click-button-on-website-using-java-script-and-speech-recognition)