# Click button on website using java-script and speech recognition

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

Newbie here. I work on a website where I have to click buttons. I need to be able to click on buttons based on their DIV ID using speech recognition. Lets say a clickable button div has an ID of one, I want to say ONE verbally and have the button clicked.

I am guessing I need Javascript click function combined with a speech recognition API. I can handle using Javascript to manipulate HTML DOM, but how do I interface with an offline speech recognition API. Which one should I use and how do I go about using it?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test speech recognition you can check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) the page include link to github with demos.

Here is my code based on color example (`<com.sun.speech.app.numbers.*>` is taken from [w3c docs about grammars](https://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;
var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;
var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; import <com.sun.speech.app.numbers.*>; grammar numbers; public <number> = <com.sun.speech.app.numbers.*>;'


var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
//recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.error);
};

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Ready to receive a number command.');
};
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var numbers = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
  console.log(event.results);
  var last = event.results.length - 1;
  var number = event.results[last][0].transcript;
  console.log(numbers[number]);
  var node = document.querySelector("#" + numbers[number]);
  if (node) {
    node.style.color = 'red';
  } 
};
</script>
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
</body>
</html>
```

unfortunetelly speech recognition is disabled for Stack Snippets but here is [link to codepen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/oMEBYR) IMO speech recognition in browsers is not very good it don't recognize words you're saying, you need to repeat the word few times to make it work.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I would be using just 3 words for the speech recognition, word "one" for clicking the div ID "one", word "two" for clicking the div ID "two" and word three for clicking div ID "three"

Comment: I need the script to run contantly in chrome console cause if I make the voice command and it clicks the requested button, the webpage will refresh with new data

Comment: @Joseph so you want to run the code when dev tools is open? You can't start recognition without user interaction, but you can detect dev tools using https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

Comment: That link is probably wrong because it check for Firebug, but I'm not sure.